# Remove Data from Address Line

Tags: regex, database

I have the following address that I pulled from a database.  I am trying to clear everything up until ST|AVE|BLVD.  I am trying to get rid of 1ST or the random 1.

1. 9999-1000 N CLARK ST 1 1
2. 4567-5678 W BELMONT AVE
3. 1200 N HAMLIN AVE 1ST 1
4. 8220 W CERMAK RD 1ST
5. 1240 W 69TH ST 1ST
6. 7901 W ADDISON ST 1ST

So that it reads:
1. 9999-1000 N CLARK ST 
2. 4567-5678 W BELMONT AVE
3. 1200 N HAMLIN AVE 
4. 8220 W CERMAK RD 
5. 1240 W 69TH ST 
6. 7901 W ADDISON ST

Comment: and you have tried what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following regex:

```
^(.*?)(\s*(?:ST|AVE|BLVD).*)$
```

Your data is in capturing group 1.

See [example here](https://regex101.com/r/yX3lD2/1).